# How to Improve haskell code that has two case of?

Tags: performance, haskell

I'm learning Haskell and I think that my code is a mess. Here it is:

```
fold (Add (e1) (e2)) = case e11 of N n -> case e22 of N m -> N (n + m); _ -> Add e11 e22
                                   _ -> Add e11 e22
  where 
    e11 = fold e1
    e22 = fold e2
```

N and Add are data types that I defined. The thing is that I don't like the way that I used two case of, so is there a way to do the same but much cleaner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my eye, it's much simpler if you pattern match on a pair with both `fold`s:

```
fold (Add e1 e2) = case (fold e1, fold e2) of
   (N n, N m) -> N (n+m)
   (e11, e22) -> Add e11 e22
```

If the result is of the form `N ...` for both, you sum them, otherwise you use `Add` on the results.

The performance should be essentially the same as that in the original code. It's even possible that both versions generate the same Core after optimization.

Comment: Didn't know you can use the case of using tuples, I assume that you can do the same for n-tuples, right?